# apend table head content into table body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive table. Basically, under certain screen size I'm changing the table a bit, using this example: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

However, the css code from that example hides the thead so I only get table body content, and I can't use :before method to put in manually like in the example because I got many different tables with different data.

What I'd like to do (if it's possible) is to write a jquery function which will check the table header content and put it before appropriate cell in the table. Markup is simple:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Job Title</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>Matman</td>
    <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>The</td>
    <td>Tick</td>
    <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Is it possible to get first element of thead (first name) and add it before 1st cell content (eg James) in each row, and similiar with other thead elements ?

Regards

**EDIT:**
@ArunPJohny posted an answer in the comments, works perfectly:

[jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/564Lxosz/1](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/564Lxosz/1)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how this is more useful for small screen sizes since you're explicitly making each cell, or each row, far wider which implies more scrolling. It's definitely 'responsive,' but I'm not sure it's responsible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/564Lxosz/1/

Comment: @DavidThomas You are right, but what are the other options ? Just cant seem to find a good solution to display tables nicely under small screen sizes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP added an answer to their question.